# Javascript Wait Seconds

Tags: javascript, sleep

How can do this please help me

these buttons remove 
With 1 second

[Remove Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfU8.png)

```
var i=0;
while(i<10) {
  var itemDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
  itemDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
  a++;
  sleep(1000); // is not working. I want wait 1 seconds and continue loop
}
```

Comment: you can use setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: thank you very much your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the setTimeout function.

this function takes two arguments, the time in milliseconds, and a callback function.

To achieve a sleep type method I would suggest changing your for loop, to a function, and then use the setTimeout function to refer back to your function.

EX:

```
var i=0;
function foo() {`enter code here`
    i++;
    if(i<10) {
        itemDivs[a].style.display = 'none';
        a++;
        setTimeout(1000,foo); //Notice there are no parentheses after the function being passed into setTimeout.
    }
};
```